# 3tier/ntier architecture - good examples need

Tags: c#, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

Currently I am working with single tier architecture. Now i want to use 3iter/ntier architecture.

Please any body provide me code samples where 3iter/ntier architecture is implemented.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of application type? Web app or client app?

Comment: I need Web application samples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this its good to start
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/three_tier_architecture.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is an n-tier web architecture.  It's usually done in layers like this:

view->controller->services->persistence

Comment: Could you provide me any basic code samples/code links.

Comment: You can learn how to do this properly if you use Spring: http://www.springframework.org.  They have documentation and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in .NET I could recommend this book for a good conceptual overview of pattenrs you could use when layering an enterprise application

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-PRO-Developer/dp/073562609X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1291115917&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

Dear pankaj are are about to create a singleton project which all you code in one so please have a look at singleton pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

and if you want to create a 3 tier project please have a look at these point

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19462-Tier-Architecture-NET-Sample-Application.aspx
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/3-Tier-Architecture-Examples.aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformsapplications/thread/143f67c0-59fa-4a21-9e6c-d0b51e98d05c

Comment: @J S Jodha: your solution lools like good but i need samples for 3-Tier architecture in web application.

Comment: Read this, too: http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/.  I don't see what Singleton has to do with n-tier.